# Form Validation using a boolean flag Angular 8

Tags: html, angular, typescript, validation, angular8

In HTML I have a `(change)="limitUser($event)"` function. In typescript I have a `for` loop which runs through each element and checks if the value is less than 10. If it exceeds 10 it sets the `inValid = true`.
In HTMl all my form fields set the value as true. I want only the form field with value greater than 10 to be set as true.

HTML Code:

```
<div *ngFor="p of data; let i = index">
<label>p.name{{i}}</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control" (change)="limitUser($event)" name="p.name{{i}}" [(ngModel)]="p.usage" id="p.name">
<div class="danger" *ngIf="inValid">
Please enter number smaller than 10
</div>
</div>
```

In typescript:

```
limitUser(event){
for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i ++) {
if (this.data[i].usage = 0 || this.data[i].usage = null || this.data[i].usage = ""){
this.data[i].usage = 0;
}
if (this.data[i].usage > 10){
this.inValid = true;
}
```

But `inValid = true` is applied to all the dynamic form fields. How can I put it only on the field whose value is larger than 10.

Comment: Your HTML is not valid, please adjust.

Comment: I have closed the </div> tag. But otherwise it is a valid HTML code as it is running fine. Its just the validation is not being applied correctly

Comment: Three attributes of `input` are missing closing quotes.

Comment: yes I closed those. Thank you for that input. I just typed the code didn't copy it. but can you figure out the issue now?

Comment: Problem is that you only have one global flag. You need a ‘invalid’ flag on each of your data items.

Comment: @mikeOne can you tell me how can I set different flags when I don't know how much data will be received from the backend. My form is created dynamically based on number of objects I receive. Can there be some way of indexing inValid flag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, `inValid` is one boolean variable and you're expecting it to hold the validity for every applicable field.

Either have a separate variable for every field, or create a method that checks the validity for each field. Let's go with the second approach:

So, your HTML code should look like this (update the `*ngIf` directive):

```
<div *ngFor="p of data; let i = index">
 <label>p.name{{i}}</label>
 <input type="text" class="form-control" name="p.name{{i}}" (change)="limitUser($event)" [(ngModel)]="p.usage" id="p.name">
 <div class="danger" *ngIf="isInvalid(i)">
  Please enter number smaller than 10
 </div>
</div>
```

And add a new method in your TS, as well as modify `limitUser()`:

```
isInvalid(index) {
 return this.data[index].usage > 10;
}

limitUser(event) {
 for (let i = 0; i < this.data.length; i ++) {
  // btw, use === to compare; == means loosely compare and = means assign
  // or just append ! to check for falsy values, like:
  if (!this.data[i].usage){
   this.data[i].usage = 0;
  }
 }
}
```

You can reuse your `inValid` variable to check the overall validity of the form, or just remove it.

UPDATE:

To disable the submit button when everything is disabled:

Modify your submit button to include a `[disabled]` attribute in the HTML:

```
...
<button type="submit" [disabled]="isFormInvalid">
...
```

And in the TS:

```
get isFormInvalid() {
 return this.data.some(datum => datum.usage > 10);
}
```

Comment: here are you suggesting i should use a for loop in ```isInvalid(index) {} ``` function too? Otherwise it will throw an error right away, isn't it?

Comment: @Bitly no need for a `forLoop`, Angular runs change detection automatically (unless specified otherwise). So, the `isInvalid` function will run automatically every time a change is detected. Try to use the the function as it is in my answer. And let me know if it works out for you :)

Comment: I am not sure why but I am getting the error for ```return this.data[i].usage < 10```

Comment: Oh shoot I made a mistake, use `index` instead of `i`. I have updated the answer. Try again @Bitly, so sorry for that

Comment: haha thats alright. This is a spot on answer. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks a ton! Cheers. Marking this as the accepted answer.

Comment: It has been a long day today, and I'm making so many small mistakes :( I am glad it works. Thanks, @Bitly!

Comment: it did @Tashi Starset

Comment: Starset I also have a button at bottom how should I disable it when any field is disabled. Thank you in advance

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217821/discussion-between-tashi-tobgay-dakpa-and-bitly).